# Monitoring JVMs Remotely in a Production Environment

Tags: java, performance, jvm, monitoring, jmx

I have used [jConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), to monitor JVMs through its GUI, and sometimes to save performance data to csv by simply right clicking on graphs. But now I have a requirement of writing JVM performance data such as Heap Memory Usage and CPU Usage of remote JVMs directly into a local file (with timestamp) without using the GUI.

I have tried many tools including the followings but they don't have the required functionalities such as connecting to remote JVMs and writing outputs to local files.

1. [JVM Top](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop)
2. [JVM Mon](https://github.com/ajermakovics/jvm-mon)

Can anyone suggest me a tool that can be used to get csv outputs which are similar to the results that can be generated through jConsole, but without using GUI.

Comment: You can collect the required metrics yourself using [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/toc.html) and write it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use `cmdline-jmxclient` to pull my MBean data, I use influx to store the data and later show it on Grafana for dashboarding, below is an example shell script which invokes the jmxclient

## cmdline-jmxclient:

If you have an MBean: `com.yourcompany.data:type=datasystem,id=0`
With an Operation called: `jmxRefresh()`

Then you can write a simple bash script (assuming you download [cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar) and put in the same directory as your script):

```
#!/bin/bash

cmdLineJMXJar=./cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar
user=yourUser
password=yourPassword
jmxHost=localhost
port=9003

#No User and password so pass '-'
echo "Available Operations for com.yourcompany.data:type=datasystem,id=0"
java -jar ${cmdLineJMXJar} ${user}:${password} ${jmxHost}:${port} com.yourcompany.data:type=datasystem,id=0

echo "Executing XML update..."
java -jar ${cmdLineJMXJar} - ${jmxHost}:${port} com.yourcompany.data:type=datasystem,id=0 jmxRefresh
```

Similarly, you can get the heap memory or any other MBean's exposed in your JVM.

Another sample script is as below

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "You need to supply both JMX host and port and metric. Exiting ..."
    exit 1
fi

JAVA_BIN="/usr/bin/java"
JMX_CMDLINE="./cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar"
APP_NAME="${1}"

if [ $3 = "DaemonThreadCount" -o $3 = "all" ]; then

  TEMPFILE=`mktemp`
  $JAVA_BIN -jar $JMX_CMDLINE - ${1}:${2}  "java.lang:type=Threading" DaemonThreadCount 2>> $TEMPFILE
  VALUE=`grep DaemonThreadCount $TEMPFILE | sed "s/.*DaemonThreadCount: //g" | cut -f2 -d:` 
  echo "$VALUE"
  rm -f $TEMPFILE

fi

if [ $3 = "HeapMemoryUsage" -o $3 = "all" ]; then

  TEMPFILE=`mktemp`
  $JAVA_BIN -jar $JMX_CMDLINE - ${1}:${2}  "java.lang:type=Memory" HeapMemoryUsage 2>> $TEMPFILE

  OUTPUT=`cat $TEMPFILE | egrep "committed:|used:" | sed "s/: /=/g"`

  for line in $OUTPUT
  do
    NAME=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d=`
    VALUE=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d=`
  done

  cat $TEMPFILE | grep used | cut -f2 -d" "
  rm -f $TEMPFILE

fi


if [ $3 = "PSPermGen" -o $3 = "all" ]; then

  rm -f $TEMPFILE

  $JAVA_BIN -jar $JMX_CMDLINE - ${1}:${2}  "java.lang:name=PS Perm Gen,type=MemoryPool" Usage 2>> $TEMPFILE

  OUTPUT=`cat $TEMPFILE | egrep "committed:|used:" | sed "s/: /=/g"`

  for line in $OUTPUT
  do
    NAME=`echo $line | cut -f1 -d=`
    VALUE=`echo $line | cut -f2 -d=`
    echo "$VALUE"
  done

fi
```